# Automatically Refresh iFrame When Change is Detected

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am making a simple electron app which allows users to preview their index.html through an iFrame which they can adjust to fit different screen sizes. I was wondering if there is a way to make the iFrame automatically refresh whenever the user makes a change to the document they are editing?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at nodemon to watch the filesystem for changes

https://nodemon.io/

Comment: how would I use this?